# Why Won't My Controller Work For Minecraft Window 10?

Tags: controllers, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I got Minecraft window ten and connected my controller from the USB. So I started the game and the controller seemed to not work. I tried everything and it still doesn't want to work. Is there something I'm missing? Or is it my laptop?

Comment: Are they supposed to work? Maybe that feature just doesn't exist.

Comment: what kind of controller is it? not a ton of controllers just work plug-and-play style. Some need software installed (like the ps4 dualshock I think).